# Nested Spring Transaction never rollback

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I am working on a service layer that logs to a database as it performs tasks. I want to ensure that this log doesn't roll back whenever an error occurs, as I should always keep a record of failed attempts. Below is sample code to explain what it is that I want.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public void performTask()
{
    //Perform task 1
    log("task1Complete");

    //Perform task 2
    log("task2Complete");
}

@Transactional()
public void log(String message)
{
    //commit message to DB
    //This should never rollback
}
```

I assume the way to do it is to start a new transaction but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to use:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

See: [Propagation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html)

Also, your TransactionManager must be configured to [allow nested transactions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/transaction/support/AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.html#setNestedTransactionAllowed%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 2):

Use :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

Be aware that calling a @Transactional method on "this" will not open a transaction if you are using JDK Proxies or CGIL Proxies. You must use AspectJ instead or call it on another object to pass through its proxy.